# Is it feasible to store user Specific Data inside in a Static Variable in Web Application 

Tags: java

I am developing a WebApplication which might be accessed concurrently nearly by 7000 users at a time .

So in this Web Application , i am using the below logic

when the User Logins in successfully , i am storing the information related to him in a ArrayList as shown .

class 1 :

```
if(successfullyloggedin)  
{
ArrayList accounts = getInfoForUser(customerId);
userinfo.accountsinfor  = accounts;
}


public ArrayList getInfoForUser(String custId)
{
ArrayList  users  = getDataFromDatabase();
return users;
}
```

class 2 :

```
public class UserInfo {
public static ArrayList accountsinfor;
}
```

class 3 :

Class 3 is a service class , whcih checks if a User is present or not to make a call

```
class services 
{


public String MakeCall(String Id)
{

    ArrayList accounts = UserInfo.accountsinfor;

if(!ID.contains(accounts ))
// Throw an Exception
}

else
{
// Its fine 
}
}
```

Please tell me if i can use this logic in a WebAplication that is used concurrently by almost 7000 users at a time . 
My concern is of using static variables .

Or please suggest if theer is even a better approach to proceed with this .

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a web application, I would create a session per user and put their specific information in there.  That's what it's for.

You don't say what the information is: credentials, ACLs, etc.  It would be easier to comment on your data structure choice if that was clear.

Comment: Initially i thought of this but if  a user logs with two LoginIDs say in  Mozilla  , the browser is creating same sessionId for both , so the second Logged user is overriding the information .

Comment: You want to prevent two simultaneous sessions from the same user.

Comment: I cant change the business functionality , as a user is right to have two LoginID 's for example  Jointaccount

Comment: OK, then live with it.  If it's the same user, overriding their own info, then it's their problem.  They shouldn't be logging in twice.  Maybe you also want to have a reasonable session timeout.  30 minutes ought to be enough for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if your arraylist contains User info or a user list as makeCall look for 'ID' in it.

Anyway, it's usually a bad idea to store stuff in static variables in a concurrent environment. If you're in a web application, I suggest you store your user information in your HttpSession  as an attribute:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use HttpSession and let container handle that for you.
Just annotate your class that is holding user information with `@SessionScoped` (of course it depends on framework you use) an let container handle every thing for you. instead of doing error prone designs ;)